# Как организовать категории в Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ребятки подскажите пожалуйста. Есть задание сделать небольшой проектик типа учет доходов и расходов с возможностью их добавлять и удалять.Также должна быть возможность добавлять и удалять категории расходов и доходов. Следовательно вопрос: Как лучше организовать сами Категории?Создать глобальную категорию Category, а потом унаследовать от нее категории IncomeCategory и ExpenseCategory, а затем просто обращаться к ним через type?Или как лучше?Посоветуйте вообще как можно спланировать такой проект.Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а сколько будет всего категорий?

Comment: Будет 2 категории всего IncomeCategory и ExpenseCategory и их можно добавлять и удалять, плюс к этому они должны быть связаны с модельками incomes и expense в которых будут создавать имя расхода/дохода, дата создания/изменения, откуда пришло/куда ушло, категория к кот относится.

Comment: тогда нет смысла создавать 3 класса. У вас приход и расход тоже в одну модель можно поместить. И добавить в неё флаг.

Comment: Не могли бы вы продемонстировать небольшим кодом, как можно это реализовать?Хотя бы примерно, чтобы иметь представление.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для вашего проекта достаточно иметь одну модель на приходы и расходы. Для удобства в модель можно добавить логическое (Boolean) поле, которое будет указывать приход это или расход.

```
 rails g scaffold Ledger title amount:number income:boolean comment:text
```

Это создаст модель, необходимые отображения и контроллер. Данная модель будет хранить и расходы, и приходы.

Для удобства работы вы можете создать дополнительные **scope** в модели.

```
 scope :income, -> { where(income: true) }
 scope :expense, -> { where(income: false) }
```

Comment: Т.е я создаю одну модель для расхода/дохода и далее просто ссылаюсь на них с помощью поля boolean?То же самое делаю одну модель для Category и также ссылаюсь к нужному?

Comment: @Максим вы делаете одну модель. Всего одну. Модель для записи прихода/расхода. Я добавил в ответ примерную модель.

Comment: С моделью для расхода и дохода понятно вроде. Таким же макаром сделать одну единственную модель для категорий?

Comment: @Максим не нужна вам модель категорий. У вас вместо категорий флаг.

Comment: Походу я понял все)Поправьте,если я ошибся.Просто хочу все воспроизвести в голове. Будет у меня одна модель и флаг кот будет ссылаться на income или expense, таким образом,если юзер захочет создать категорию Food к примеру, он просто воспользуется формой,где напишет в title Food, в amount $5 к примеру, в description описание, далее выберет дату , выберет из селекта income или expense и нажмет Add и все?

Comment: да. и ли вы можете создать 2 разных формы со скрытым полем. или форму с двумя разными кнопками и в контроллере обрабатывать.

Comment: Супер))Спасибо вам огромное))Все теперь стало понятно.

Comment: Справедливости ради, модель категории при таком раскладе может существовать, но не иметь собственной таблицы, служа эдаким шлюзиком для получения элементов. На ActiveRecord модели не заканчиваются :)

Comment: @D-side единственного правильного решения не существует. Но я стараюсь придерживаться принципа YAGNI - особенно с новичками.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman не существует. Я только указываю только на то, что модели, как понятие, не прибиты к БД гвоздями. И то, что какая-то сущность лишена таблицы, вовсе не лишает её права быть моделью. **При необходимости**, т. к. YAGNI тоже дело.